# better regular expression for matching strings?

Tags: java, regex

I have a "`moreinfo`" Directory which has some html file and other folder. I am searching the file in the `moreinfo` directory( and not sub directory in `moreinfo`)  matches with `toolId*`.The names of the file is same as toolId],

[image]

Below is a code snippet how i writing it, In case my `toolId = delegatedAccess` the list returns 2 file (`delegatedAccess.html & delegatedAccess.shopping.html`) based on the wide card filter(`toolId*`)

Is their a better way of writing the regular expression that check until last occurring period and return the file that matches exactly with my toolId?

```
infoDir =/Users/moreinfo


 private String getMoreInfoUrl(File infoDir, String toolId) {
        String moreInfoUrl = null;
        try {
            Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(infoDir, new WildcardFileFilter(toolId+"*"), null);
            if (files.isEmpty()==false) {
            File mFile = files.iterator().next();
            moreInfoUrl = libraryPath + mFile.getName(); // toolId;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        M_log.info("unable to read moreinfo" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return moreInfoUrl;

}
```

Comment: So in your example you want it to only return the `delegatedAccess.html` file? Try `toolID + "\\.[^\\.]*$"`

Comment: @clcto: yes. let me try yours now

Comment: My example is regex, but `WildcardFileFilter` doesn't use regex. I don't think there is a way to specify what you want with the `WildcardFileFilter`, but you could iterate over the list that it returns.

Comment: @clcto: yes, you are correct. WildCardFileFilter do not use regex.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you've got a rather small finite set of permissible file extensions?  In this case you could write the regex to check for `toolId.<permissible_extensions>`, something like `Pattern.compile("^(" + toolId + "\\.(?:html?|aspx?|jsp?))$");`.

Comment: @adamdc78: No i can't assume that i will have a permissible file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i end up doing with all the great comments. I did string manipulation to solve my problem. As Regex was not right solution to it.

```
private String getMoreInfoUrl(File infoDir, String toolId) {
    String moreInfoUrl = null;
    try { 
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(infoDir, new WildcardFileFilter(toolId+"*"), null);
        if (files.isEmpty()==false) {
                for (File mFile : files) {
                    int lastIndexOfPeriod = mFile.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
                    String fNameWithOutExtension = mFile.getName().substring(0,lastIndexOfPeriod);
                    if(fNameWithOutExtension.equals(toolId)) {
                        moreInfoUrl = libraryPath + mFile.getName();
                        break;
                    }

                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        M_log.info("unable to read moreinfo" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return moreInfoUrl;

}
```

Comment: Your `if (files.isEmpty()==false)` can be removed all together. The `for` loop will only iterate on elements that are in the list.